# Python real time writing to ppt

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to run a python code that opens a ppt presentation and fills it up with information. After this stage, I need the ppt input from ppt to generate new content on the presentation itself. Real time data reading and writing without saving, closing and opening the ppt. What apis or methods would you recommend?

Comment: You'll need to say more. Why do you write the initial information to the PPTX file? Why wouldn't just gather all your inputs in some convenient form like JSON or whatever and then write the PPTX once you have all of it? To get a reasoned answer you need to say _why_ you want to do it this way.

Comment: I need to write to the ppt file while it is open and for the user to have the chance to keep editing the file while the python code is running and changing the ppt itself. So let's say I have ppt open and I add a text, I want the code to create 10 slides with the same text after it for example. Hope this makes it clearer. Thanks!